# Querying with SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query in sql which gives me distinct Pan details and the count of that Pan in the table where the Name is appearing more than once

For example: Consider the table below

```
ID  Name Pan
1   ABC 123
2   ABC 123
3   DEF 456
4   ABC 124
5   WW  234
6   WW  2345
```

The result expected is :

```
Pan  Name Count1
123  ABC   2
124  ABC   1
234  WW    1
2345 WW    1
```

Could someone please help me out with this.

Comment: Please try something yourself first. If Any error then expert will solve here definitely.

Comment: I did try  'SELECT pan, name, count(id) FROM cleverchalk.new having count(name) >1;' but it does not give me the desired result

Comment: Pan 1234 is on the results but not on the source data. Pans 456 and 124 are on the source data but not on results. Very difficult to know what you want with that mess.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
           FROM 
              ( SELECT pan
                     , name
                     , COUNT(*) total
                  FROM my_table
                 GROUP 
                    BY pan
                     , name 
              ) x
           JOIN my_table y
             ON y.name = x.name
            AND y.pan <> x.pan
```

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry! This is exactly what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Hope below statement help you out.

```
    SELECT PAN, NAME , COUNT(ID) FROM TAB_PAN GROUP BY PAN, NAME HAVING COUNT(ID)>1
```

As per conversation the requirement seems different.
The below code will work fine.

Schema for given data

```
    SELECT * INTO #TAB FROM (
    SELECT 1 ID ,   'ABC' NAME , 123 PAN
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,   'ABC', 123
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 ,  'DEF' ,456
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 ,  'ABC', 124
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 ,  'WW' , 234
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 ,  'WW'  ,2345
    )AS A
```

Logic for the required case

```
     SELECT PAN, NAME,COUNT(ID) ACTUAL_COUNT   FROM #TAB t
     WHERE (SELECT COUNt(NAME) FROM #TAB WHERE NAME= t.NAME) >1 
     GROUP BY PAN, NAME
```

Comment: Thanks Shakeer but this does not eliminate single entries like 'DEF' name above. When I use 'having count(name)>1' it prints out -->123 ABC 2

Comment: If you need restriction after grouping the result set use HAVING clause and if it is before grouping use WHERE clause. @user3201181

Comment: Hi Shakeer., Still the same result

Comment: Check my new answer @user3201181